# .NET WebBrowser Control - Override script of IFrame?

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe, inject

i would like to suspend/disable window.alert and window.onbeforeunload of any website browsed by Windows.Form.WebBrowser Control. I successfully override these functions when they are called on main site, but if they are called on an Iframe, I can't still override this function.

To reproduce the case, I make 2 HTML files

1. Test HTML files: Main site and remote site

Main site:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
      function confirmExit()
      {
        return "Onbeforeunload from main";
      }
    alert("Alert from main")
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    <iframe src="remote.html">
</body>
</html>
```

Remote site:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
      function confirmExit()
      {
        return "Onbeforeunload from remote";
      }
    alert("Alert from remote")
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Copy these 2 files into same folder (for example copy to Desktop)

1. Load main site into webbrowser and override the window.alert / window.onbeforeunload

Initialize:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"file://127.0.0.1/C$/Users/ServusKevin/Desktop/main.html");
webBrowser1.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigated);
webBrowser1.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(webBrowser1_ProgressChanged);
```

Code:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteMe();
}

private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteMe();
}

private void ExecuteMe()
{
    DisableAlertIE(webBrowser1.Document as HtmlDocument);
    HtmlDocument document = (webBrowser1.Document as HtmlDocument);
    if (document != null)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < document.Window.Frames.Count; index++)
        {
            try
            {
                DisableAlertIE((document.Window.Frames[index]).Document);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

private void DisableAlertIE(HtmlDocument document)
{
    if (document != null)
    {
        //HTMLDocument document = wbIE.Document as HTMLDocument;
        HtmlElement scriptSuppressed = document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement scriptDomElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptSuppressed.DomElement;
        scriptDomElement.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptDomElement.text = @"window.alert = function () { }; window.confirm = function () { }; window.prompt = function () { }; window.print = function () { }; window.onbeforeunload = function () {};";

        foreach (HtmlElement head in document.GetElementsByTagName("head"))
        {
            head.AppendChild(scriptSuppressed);
        }
    }
}
```

When I let the program run, the window.alert and window.onbeforeunload of main site was successfully suspended but the alert and onbeforeunload of remote site are still called.

Question: How should I improve my code to suspend the alert and onbeforeunload of remote site?